# Error upgrading Ruby to 1.9.3 on OS X 10.7.5 using zsh - Command not found: rvm

Tags: ruby, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've been trying to follow this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/) to upgrade Ruby but I'm getting "Command not found: rvm" in Terminal.

```
➜  ~  rvm
zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: rvm
```

I'm getting stuck after Step 2: Load RVM into the Shell. I've actually added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

into the .zshrc file with some additional lines I've found in other answers to similar question. The file contents now:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# For Ruby 1.9
__rvm_project_rvmrc 
alias rvm-promt=$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt # added 2013/09/13
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how many often would you like to wait before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true" 

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

I've download XCode 4.6.3 and installed the Command Line tools. How do I get this upgrade to work? Thanks.

Edit: I relaunched Terminal before trying the rvm command.

Comment: Then you didn't install RVM

Comment: Did you open a new window or run the rvm shell file line in your current window?

Comment: Did you run 'curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled'?

Comment: Thank you shadowmaru, for the correct code! It appears to be installing now. (It didn't give me any errors before, so I didn't know the code from the tutorial was working or not.)